# How to remove selected property from ListBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.listboxfor

I am using Html.ListBoxFor to populate a list of entries from MVC Model

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.DetailsBook, new SelectList(Model.DetailsBook), new { @id = "BookList" })
```

Now everything works expect that the list items by default selected. Is there anyway I can remove that and just populate these values in list box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you're using `DetailsBook` as both the list and the main expression.

So what you need to do is create another property, and use that for 'selected values'. e.g.

Model:

```
public string Details { get; set; }
public List<string> DetailsBook { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Details, new SelectList(Model.DetailsBook), new { @id = "BookList" })
```